# android send link and open with specific application

Tags: android, email, android-intent, sms

I am developing metting scheduler . In my android application I like to achive this flow :

1. Android send message "Meeting setup at 15.30" as link to another user.
2. The receiver will open sms or email and pressing link will open application .
   if application not exist then Android market will open.
3. If application exist meeting will apear in shceduler.

How can I do this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not possible.

First, while there are a lot of Android devices, plenty of people will "open sms or email" using something other than an Android device. It is not possible to open the Play Store (which I assume is what you mean by "Android market") on a non-Android device. Whether it is possible to open your app via a "link" on a non-Android device would depend on the configuration of that other device.

Even if we limit the discussion to where the recipient elects to "open sms or email" on an Android device, there is no means by which you can, from a single "link", indicate that your app should start *or* open the Play Store. Your options are:

1. Have the link be an `http://` URL, with an appropriate `<intent-filter>` for that URL in your manifest. In that case, for devices that have your app installed, your app will appear in an app chooser along with the user's browser(s), and the user can elect to launch your activity. For devices that do not have your app installed, the user will probably view a Web page at that URL, and there you can provide instructions to help the user download your application.
2. Have the link be some proprietary scheme (e.g., `user3004288://`), which can eliminate the app chooser. However, it means that your link will not be clickable in many cases, as email and SMS clients may not recognize your custom scheme. Also, if your app is not installed, the user cannot do anything.
3. Have the link be to your Play Store listing, in which case if your app is already installed, the user will have an "Open" button in the Play Store screen, which the user can use to open the existing installed copy of your app.

Comment: Ok, If I back to my initial problem : notify another user on meeting .

Comment: I can resolve it , only if other user have same application, and meeting request send via this application